# How to make 3 rows of NavBar in Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, web

I wanna start learning about website. I just have experience in native php and css. I have no experience with framework (bootstrap). Now, Im starting learning about framework as I know it's important.

So I want to make a website with bootstrap for layouting. I need to make a fixed-top navbar. But I have 3 rows as my navbar.

I have search and tried combine [This First One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372092/two-rows-in-a-navbar-with-a-column-spanning-two-rows), [This Second One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112363/bootstrap-navbar-with-two-rows), [This Third One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080668/creating-a-bootstrap-twin-navbar-only-2nd-row-collapsible), and many more.

I have took almost 3 days to combine it. But not get what I want. Frustated T_T.

Can anyone please help me develop 3 rows fixed navbar (in simple code, so as a starter I could understand and do improvement).
The problem always about my logo image.

Here is the look which I want to make:

[image: Here is the look which I want to make]

I'll appriciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: When click on burger menu, first two bars should collapse? or all of them? Can you share with us your current code?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? demo: http://www.bootply.com/lp3BUeCXzf
this one has three menus last menu with collapse icon

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="divide-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="divide-text">Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-lower" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse-buttons" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```